# PHP - selecting a particular entry with YQL

Tags: php, xml, arrays, yql

so I'm using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to get a youtube user's subscriber count.

to do this I'm making a query using a URL like this:

```
$query = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='.urlencode("SELECT * FROM xml WHERE url='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{$id}'").'&format=json&callback=';
```

then I decode the response and find the array entry I'm looking for like this:

```
  $response = json_decode($response, true);
  $subscriber_count = $response['query']['results']['entry']['statistics']['subscriberCount'];
```

it works fine, except I don't like the way I'm doing this :)
I mean, is there a way I can get the `subscriberCount` value directly from the `$query` URL above? I don't need the entire XML, just that one entry.

Comment: What do you mean by, *"directly from the `$query` URL"* ?

Comment: well the query url is passed to curl which makes a request to yahoo for the xml. I was hoping there's a way to request yahoo only the data I need, not the complete xml structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to limit the amount of data that is returned by YQL to the data you are really interested in by doing sth like this:

```
SELECT statistics.subscriberCount FROM xml WHERE ...
```

Still you would have some structural XML/JSON elements around the number that you are interested in but at least it is less (see below). Not sure if that is what you wanted?

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2011-01-06T23:21:32Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
            <yt:statistics
                xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" subscriberCount="7"/>
        </entry>
    </results>
</query>
```