# Selecting a particular field from Google's "unofficial" weather API using YQL

Tags: xml, select, yql, google-weather-api

[According to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417341/php-selecting-a-particular-entry-with-yql) I can select individual XML fields with a YQL query and it works just fine when I test it:

```
SELECT statistics.subscriberCount FROM xml
WHERE url='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{$id}'
```

However when I try to select individual XML fields from [Google's "unofficial" weather XML API](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi) I always get empty results (though `SELECT *` does work).

I know my understanding of both XML and YQL are not complete but what am I missing? [(Here's my query in the YQL console)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20current_conditions%20FROM%20xml%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi%22)

[(I have managed to query it using XPATH with the `itemPath` parameter and `SELECT *`)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20xml%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi%22%20AND%20itemPath=%22//current_conditions/temp_c%22)

### My intended query

```
SELECT current_conditions FROM xml
WHERE url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi"
```

### Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2012-02-27T11:56:15Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results/>
</query>
```

### Results of `SELECT *`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2012-02-27T11:57:18Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <xml_api_reply version="1">
            <weather mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" module_id="0"
                row="0" section="0" tab_id="0">
                <forecast_information>
                    <city data="Tbilisi, Tbilisi"/>
                    <postal_code data="Tbilisi"/>
                    <latitude_e6 data=""/>
                    <longitude_e6 data=""/>
                    <forecast_date data="2012-02-27"/>
                    <current_date_time data="1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"/>
                    <unit_system data="US"/>
                </forecast_information>
                <current_conditions>
                    <condition data="Overcast"/>
                    <temp_f data="34"/>
                    <temp_c data="1"/>
                    <humidity data="Humidity: 80%"/>
                    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/cloudy.gif"/>
                    <wind_condition data="Wind: NE at 6 mph"/>
                </current_conditions>
                <forecast_conditions>
                    <day_of_week data="Mon"/>
                    <low data="28"/>
                    <high data="37"/>
                    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
                    <condition data="Mostly Sunny"/>
                </forecast_conditions>
                <forecast_conditions>
                    <day_of_week data="Tue"/>
                    <low data="30"/>
                    <high data="41"/>
                    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
                    <condition data="Mostly Sunny"/>
                </forecast_conditions>
                <forecast_conditions>
                    <day_of_week data="Wed"/>
                    <low data="30"/>
                    <high data="43"/>
                    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
                    <condition data="Mostly Sunny"/>
                </forecast_conditions>
                <forecast_conditions>
                    <day_of_week data="Thu"/>
                    <low data="27"/>
                    <high data="43"/>
                    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
                    <condition data="Partly Sunny"/>
                </forecast_conditions>
            </weather>
        </xml_api_reply>
    </results>
</query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out not to be anything special about the Google weather API but about how the `SELECT` parameter interacts with the `itemPath` parameter in a YQL query.

Personally I find the YQL documentation quite difficult to use for those of us with only a rudimentary understanding of some of the technologies on which it relies.

It seems that when you `SELECT ... FROM rss` that there is an implied `itemPath` which points to the repeated `item` field of a feed. But when you `SELECT ... FROM xml` you need to specify an `itemPath` manually. If there's no repeating part of your XML it's pretty arbitrary what you set it to.

Now once you have an `itemPath` set you can then `SELECT` particular fields using the dot notation. Note that you can specify subfields which are XML attributes using the `SELECT` dot notation, but you cannot specify them using the slash notation in the `itemPath` but no diagnostics help you find such a beginner error...

### My new query

```
SELECT current_conditions.temp_c.data FROM xml
WHERE url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Tbilisi"
AND itemPath="//weather"
```

### Results

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2012-03-01T10:22:41Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <weather>
            <current_conditions>
                <temp_c data="3"/>
            </current_conditions>
        </weather>
    </results>
</query>
```